# StructureMapBuildPlanException : Unable to create Build Plan

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

I am creating a sample app with AngularJS, Asp.Net Web API 2, Generic Repository Pattern in data access Layer (I have IRepository and Repository added in the DAL Project) and I have UserContext class which uses CodeFirst Approach.

I have added StructureMap.WebAPI2 Nuget in my Web API Project. My IRepository code is

```
public interface IRepository<C,T>
{
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Edit(T entity);
        T GetById(int id);
        void Save();
}
```

My Repository class is as follows:

```
public class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<C, T> where T : class where C : DbContext,new()
{
        private C _entities = new C();
public C Context
        {
            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }
        protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

        public Repository(DbContext dataContext)
        {
            DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {

            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            Save();
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            Save();
        }

        public void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State =            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }



        public T GetById(int id)
        {
          return  DbSet.Find(id);

        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

In My Web API Project My controller has a parameter

```
public class UserAccountController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IRepository<UserContext,UserAccount> _useraccount;

        [DefaultConstructor]
        public UserAccountController(IRepository<UserContext, UserAccount> useraccount)
        {
            _useraccount = useraccount;
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public int AddUser(UserAccount useracct)
        {
            UserAccount user3 = new UserAccount() { Name = "Oza", Email = "oza@email.com", Address = "Dover" };
            _useraccount.Add(user3);
            return user3.Id;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserByID(int id)
        {
           UserAccount useracc =  _useraccount.GetById(id);            
            return Ok(useracc);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<UserAccount> GetUsersList()
        {
            return _useraccount.GetAll().ToList<UserAccount>();
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public void ModifyUser(UserAccount useracc, int id)
        {
            if (useracc.Id == id)
            {
                _useraccount.Edit(useracc);
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteUser(int id)
        {
            UserAccount useracc = _useraccount.GetById(id);
            if (useracc != null)
            {
                _useraccount.Delete(useracc);
            }

        }
    }
```

My WebAPI Config has following code

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.

            App_Start.StructuremapWebApi.Start();
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );



        }
    }
```

MyDefaultRegistry.cs (which got added in DependencyResolution Folder after adding the nuget) has

public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

```
    public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();

                scan.Assembly("EntityFramework");
                scan.Assembly("EntityFramework.SqlServer");
                scan.Assembly("DataAccessLayer");
                scan.Assembly("DomainModels");
                scan.Assembly("DataRepositories");


            });
        //For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
        For<DataRepositories.IRepository<UserContext, UserAccount>>().Use<DataRepositories.Repository<UserContext, UserAccount>>();
    }
```

Finally my Global.Asax I have added below lines of Code

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            IContainer container = DependencyResolution.IoC.Initialize();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        }
```

Now when I try to run the application and access the service from my browser it throws the following error.

```
Unable to create a build plan for concrete type System.Data.Entity.DbContext
new DbContext(String nameOrConnectionString)
┗ String nameOrConnectionString = Required primitive dependency is not      explicitly defined
1.) Attempting to create a BuildPlan for Instance of System.Data.Entity.DbContext -- System.Data.Entity.DbContext
2.) new Repository`2(*Default of DbContext*)
3.) Repository<UserContext, UserAccount>
4.) Instance of IRepository<UserContext, UserAccount> (Repository<UserContext, UserAccount>)
5.) new UserAccountController(*Default of IRepository<UserContext, UserAccount>*)
6.) NAPService.Controllers.UserAccountController
7.) Instance of NAPService.Controllers.UserAccountController
8.) Container.GetInstance(NAPService.Controllers.UserAccountController)
```

Comment: Hi Guys,  After struggling a lot I got the solution. I just had to add following line of code in Defaultregistry.cs

Comment: For<DbContext>().Use<UserContext>();

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add a solution. Would you do that in the answer box below?

Comment: Regarding the correct format for questions, thanks for being concerned about that. Please do not ask in questions if the question is OK - that is just chat that will need editing out. Please do not add "please help me" since that is redundant, and please do not add "urgent", since it is never urgent for volunteers. Thanks!